# Cannot iterate over array passed as prop to React js child component

Tags: reactjs, properties, state

I have a react component where I collect people's contact information from Google People API after having their permission. I collect the contacts name, email, phone numbers and addresses in an array. Then I pass the array as a prop to the child component. But although the child component apparently receives the prop, the console says its length is zero.

The console output reads like this:
[image: Preview of react component]

The code where I build the array of objects is like this (I had previously built the whole object, now I just append strings to test if it's working, but I need to pass an array of objects to the component props):

```
    var Elementos = [];
    (I call the google api here).then(function (resp) {

            var Fila = 0;
            resp.result.connections.forEach(list => {
                var Contacto = {}
                if (list.names != undefined && list.names.length > 0) {
                    Contacto.Nombre = list.names[0].displayName;
                }
                if (list.emailAddresses != undefined && list.emailAddresses.length > 0) {
                    Contacto.Email = list.emailAddresses[0].value;
                }
                if (list.addresses != undefined && list.addresses.length > 0) {
                    Contacto.Direccion = list.addresses[0].value;
                }
                if(list.phoneNumbers != undefined && list.phoneNumbers.length > 0){
                    var telefonos = "";
                    list.phoneNumbers.forEach(item=>{
                        telefonos+=item.value+",";
                    })
                    telefonos = telefonos.substring(0, telefonos.length-1);
                    Contacto.Telefono = telefonos;
                }
                if (list.names != undefined && list.names.length > 0 && list.emailAddresses != undefined && list.emailAddresses.length > 0 && list.phoneNumbers != undefined && list.phoneNumbers.length > 0) {
                    Fila++;
                    Contacto.Numero = Fila;
                    Elementos.push(Contacto.Nombre +" "+Contacto.Telefono);
                }
            });
            return resp;
        })
        return datos;
    }).then((respuesta) => {
        this.setState(prevEstado => {
            prevEstado.Contactos = Elementos, prevEstado.DirectorioCargado = true;
            return prevEstado});});
```

Then I pass the properties like this:

```
return (
    <div>
        <DirectorioContactos titulo="Directorio de contactos" initialize={this.state.Contactos} />
    </div>
)
```

And finally in the child component I do this (after setting the state in the constructor):

```
render() {
        console.log('en propiedades');
        console.log(this.state.Contactos);
        console.log(this.state.Contactos.length);

        const algo = ["Entonces","Tu","Valiste","Tres kilos"];
        return (
            <div>
            <Jumbotron>
                <h2>{this.props.titulo}</h2>
                <p>Invita a los contactos que desees. Les enviaremos un correo informando tu decisión de agregarlos a nuestro directorio.</p>
            </Jumbotron>
            <Table striped bordered condensed hover>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Nombre y Apellidos</th>
                        <th>Teléfono</th>
                        <th>Correo electrónico</th>
                        <th>Dirección</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>{this.state.Contactos.map((item, i) => {
            return(<tr key={i}>
                <td>{i}</td>
                <td>{item}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                </tr>);})
                }</tbody>
            </Table>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

But as you can see in the image nothing get's rendered -the line in the console that reads 0 in the image, if you look carefully is the output to a call to `console.log(the property.length)`-. I also tested the map function and it works correctly when I use the constant value `algo` like `algo.map((item, i)`.

So my question is ¿what I'm doing wrong? Consider please that I'm new to React, and from what I've read I understand it is possible to pass properties like this, I would even say that I understand it is the purpose of React js.

UPDATE: From the comments I've read (and also what I have read about React js) I really think that I'm missing something that I cannot put into words here: I think it's something about my understanding of what state and props are, because I found the problem begins when I set the `Contactos`state. I did this:

```
.then((respuesta) => {
                this.setState({Contactos:Elementos, DirectorioCargado :true
                },()=>{
                    console.log('Después de cargar estado');
                    console.log(this.state.Contactos);
                    console.log(this.state.Contactos.length);
                });
```

And from right there it shows there's a length of zero in the array, although the log shows elements in it. For reference, I do this in the constructor of the parent component:

```
super();
        this.state = {
            Persona: {
                Nombres: '',
                ApellidoPaterno: '',
                ApellidoMaterno: '',
                Telefono: '',
                Calle: '',
                NumeroExterior: '',
                NumeroInterior: '',
                Colonia: '',
                Localidad: '',
                EntidadFederativa: '',
                CodigoPostal: '',
                Email: '',
                Mensaje: '',
                RecibeOfertas: false,
                InvitaContactos: false,
            },
            Contactos: [],
            DirectorioCargado: false
```

I ask again, is there a way to correctly set the array property `Contactos`. Forgive me as I said I'm just starting with React.

Answer (score 1):

In child component you are trying to access `this.state.Contactos` but you pass contact list as `initialize` property. It should be available inside child component as `this.props.initialize`.

Comment: I have already tried using the prop directly: `console.log('en propiedades');
        console.log(this.props.initialize);
        console.log(this.props.intialize.length);` shows the same output, and still length is zero for some reason that I really wish I could formulate as it is the core of my question

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on my assumption since I cannot check the whole source code. I guess the `DirectorioContactos` component is a PureComponent.

Let's say you have a React component with state and you initialized it like this

```
var Elementos = [];
this.state = {
  Contactos: Elementos
}

// in render
<PureChildComponent initialize={this.state.Contactos} />
```

And then you update it like this

```
Elementos.push("foo");
this.setState({
  Contactos: Elementos
});
```

If the PureChildComponent is a PureComponent, then it won't get rerendered even after you update `Elementos`. This is because you updated `Contactos` by **mutating it directly**, which means the reference of `Contactos` hasn't been changed. And React won't rerender a PureComponent unless the reference is updated.
So instead of `Elementos.push("foo");`, the right way is

```
this.setState({
  Contactos: [...Elementos, "foo"] // always create a new array
});
```

---

Besides, from the [official document](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate),

> state is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied. It should not be directly mutated.

So instead of doing

```
this.setState(prevEstado => {
  prevEstado.Contactos = Elementos, prevEstado.DirectorioCargado = true;
  return prevEstado;
});
```

the right way is

```
this.setState(prevEstado => ({
  ...prevEstado,
  Contactos: Elementos,
  DirectorioCargado: true,
}));
```

or just

```
this.setState({
  Contactos: Elementos,
  DirectorioCargado: true,
});
```

because React will shallowly merge the new state with the previous state for you.

Comment: I'm really not interested in changing the state from one component to another, I just want to manipulate the prop I pass to the child, in another state owned by the child component. I'll try what you mention, but my doubt is if there's something fundamentally wrong with what I did and have explained

Comment: If `DirectorioContactos` is a PureComponent, then it wouldn't be rerendered unless you change the reference. That's where I guess you did something "fundamentally wrong". I cannot find out anything else unless you post the full code

Comment: Yes, I think I get what you mean, the problem I face is I push the elements to the array before I set the state because as you have seen I return from a promise and only then I have access to the state, I cannot currently do what you suggest with `Contactos: [...Elementos, "foo"]`. By the way, what does that code mean? Do I have to add the current element in a `forEach` using that syntax. Excuse me I hadn't seen it like that. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs) I guess I'll have to refactor my code

Comment: Ah sorry, instead of `Contactos: [...Elementos, "foo"]`, you can do `Contactos : Elementos.concat(["foo"])`, they do the same thing. `Contactos: [...Elementos, "foo"]` is the [new ES6 syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: And the problem is not because "you push the elements to the array before I set the state", it's because doing `Elementos.push("foo")` will not change the reference of `Elementos.push `, but doing `Elementos = Elementos.concat(["foo"])` will. And depends on this React will decide to rerender the component or not if you are using PureComponent